# Why $(\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}) (\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}) = (\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}) p^0$ for Pauli matrices?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, quantum-spin, spinors, dirac-matrices

I am trying to verify that the following equation is true:
$$(\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}) (\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}) = (\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}) p^0$$ where $p^\mu=(p^0,\vec{p})$ is the four momentum operator and $\vec{\sigma}$ is the Pauli matrices vector. This equation was taken from Ashok Das' QFT [book](http://gr.xjtu.edu.cn/c/document_library/get_file?p_l_id=21699&folderId=2383653&name=DLFE-82650.pdf), pg 96, eq. 3.135.

I expanded both sides and found that the LHS is $$(\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}) (\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p})=\begin{pmatrix} (p^1)^2+(p^2)^2+(p^3)^2&0\\ 0&(p^1)^2+(p^2)^2+(p^3)^2\end{pmatrix},$$
while the RHS is $$(\vec{\sigma}\cdot\vec{p}) p^0=\begin{pmatrix} p^3p^0&(p^1-ip^2)p^0\\ (p^1+ip^2)p^0&-p^3p^0\end{pmatrix}.$$

How should I proceed further to verify that the equation is true?

Comment: The identity you mention is definitely not true. To go from the 2nd to 3rd equation in (3.135), the author uses (3.134).

Comment: @Pahar Thx I get it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equation 3.135 does not say this. It says
$$
({\boldsymbol \sigma}\cdot {\bf p})({\boldsymbol \sigma}\cdot {\bf p}) u_R(p)= {\bf p}^2 u_R(p),
$$
which is very different. It also says
$$
({\boldsymbol \sigma}\cdot {\bf p})u_R(p)=p^0 u_R(p)
$$
which says that  the spinor $u_R(p)$ is a solution of the Weyl equation.